# How to handle disposing in Observable RxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I am implementing `Observable` it should just download a file from network divided into multiple parts.

Here is my implementation

```
 private static class MultipartDownloadObservable extends Observable<String> implements Cancellable {
     @Override
        protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super String> observer) {
            // Start loading
            subscriber = observer;
            progressBundle = new ProgressBundle<>();
            startDownloading();
        }

        @Override
        public void cancel() throws Exception {
            if (!lastDownloadingInfo.isFinish()) {
                okHttpClient.dispatcher().queuedCalls().stream().filter(call -> call.request().tag().equals(url)).forEach(Call::cancel);
            }
            if (subscriber != null) {
                subscriber.onComplete();
            }
        }
}
```

In my code I am creating an instance of this class and then call the `dispose` method on a `Disposable` object return from subscribe method.

```
 downloadSubscription.dispose();
```

However it throws an error.

```
java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted
```

How can I implement disposing of `Observable` correctly ? I've tried to implement `Canceble` interface, however the `cancel` method is not called.

Comment: There is no reason for extending `Observable`. Use `Observable.create()` instead. Some classical APIs respond to cancellation via `InterruptedIOException`; you can't do much about it but suppress it.

Comment: @akarnokd, thanks but I need to catch this exception in order to cancel request

Answer (score 2):

Note that `java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted` not come from rx. It's an exception of java.io. For your `dispose()` action, rxJava is forced to un-subscribe and that interrupted thread during network request execution.

You can't really tell an observable to cancel a network request as rxJava has no knowledge of the code that is running inside of the Observable. What you can do is use the `doOnUnsubscribe` to check whether the network request is still running and if it is cancel it, then just unsubscribe when you want to cancel.